# How to Web Distribution like Firebase App Distribution?

Tags: web-development, deployment, angular

I am looking for a way to let Web QA tester to test website with specific version. So, Web QA tester can say things like "this X is broken since version A.B.C".

The current test/release process:

1. developer create a feature branch from staging.
2. commit to the feature branch.
3. developer merge the feature branch to the dev branch.
4. CI/CD dev.
5. QA test the dev.domain.com.
6. QA says no problem.
7. developer merge the feature branch to the staging branch.

What I want is:

(5) QA test the dev.domain.com (QA tester can select specific version).

Something like Firebase App Distribution, but for web with server side rendering capability.

Is it possible?

What I've tried:

1. Honestly, I have not try anything yet. I still use `domain.com`, `staging.domain.com`, `dev.domain.com`.

Comment: Can you elaborate what your current test/release process looks like and what you would like to achieve with "test a specific version"?

Comment: The current test/release process: (1) developer create a feature branch from staging, (2) commit to the feature branch. (3) developer merge the feature branch to the dev branch (4) CI/CD dev (5) QA test the dev.domain.com (6) QA says no problem (7) developer merge the feature branch to the staging branch. What I want is (5) QA test the dev.domain.com (QA tester can select specific version).

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include this information instead of replying in comments.

Comment: Is your team doing anything right now to associated a version or identifier with each deployment?

Comment: we do have version. but only limited to release.